# How can I use a subclass in a parameter of a superclass method?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm very new to C++ and I have a problem passing a vector of pointers to objects. Specifically the problem is the objects are a subclass of the class the method is in. I'm getting an error:

```
'Player' was not declared in this scope
```

`Player` is a subclass of `Visual` and in my file Visual.cpp I have the following function which is also declared in my header file.

```
bool Visual::DrawStatusInformation(Timer* timer, std::vector<Player*>* playerList) {
    // Draw Info
}
```

I have tried forward declaring `class Player;` in my header file but I get the error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Player’
error: forward declaration of ‘struct Player’
```

I think the problem is that my definitions are circular, Player extends Visual but Visual must know about Player in order to be able to deal with a vector of Player pointers.

**My question is:**

If it is possible, how can I use a subclass in a parameter of a superclass method?

Comment: The Q is: Why should your Base class be aware of any of its derived classes? Ideally, it should not.That is the problem in your design.

Comment: It does not know what `Player` is so it gives you a compile error.

Comment: You could cast your descendant classes into their parent type before passing them in, but basically Als had it right when they said that your architecture is wrong and upside-down.

Comment: Would it be a better design if DrawStatusInformation is moved into a derived class as well and the two derived classes were aware of each other? Or do you think I will I run into the same problem again?

Comment: Well, without really knowing what you were trying to do it is hard to say! But I rather suspect that `DrawStatusInformation` really belongs outside that class hierachy, if it is to take a vector of `Visual` or `Player`. A method which just requests a class instance draw its own status seems a bit more of a sensible architecture... but again, it is hard to say anything really helpful without some in-depth understanding of what you wanted to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Player extends Visual but Visual must know about Player in order to be able to deal with a vector of Player pointers.

By files:

- **Player.h** - include `Visual.h` & move implementations to implementation file
- **Player.cpp** - should be OK
- **Visual.h** - forward declare `Player`
- **Visual.cpp** - include `Player.h`

This just fixes the compilation error, but your design also seems faulty. If `Player` is derived from `Visual`, why does the method

```
Visual::DrawStatusInformation(Timer* timer, std::vector<Player*>* playerList)
```

exist? I'm sure you can replace it with

```
Visual::DrawStatusInformation(Timer* timer, std::vector<Visual*>* playerList)
```

and override it in `Player`. Also, why a `vector*` and not a `vector&`?

Comment: @Als I have, have you read the answer? I'm saying he should include Player.h in the implementation file.

Comment: OP did not show his header file which defines the `class Visual`, Your answer just assumes that the type `Player` is being used in such a way that its memory layout need not be known in the header which defines `Visual`, Clearly the problem here is that OP has a bad(in fact wrong)design.Your answer had no mention of it whatsoever when I downvoted and added the comment, You might have stealth edited it later on but the answer to this problem is clearly change in design not workarounds.

Comment: The OP's whole design stinks... why pass a Timer pointer and Visual pointer? Should be const references.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider redesigning. Inheritance models the *is-a* relationship, and that in turn means that in your design, `Player` *is-a* `Visual` and thus it knows how to `DrawStatusInformation` of other `Player`s. Does this seem sensible?

You might want to provide an interface that every element that is drawable implements, including `Player`, and then provide a type that is able to *draw* anything that is drawable, and potentially `Player`s in particular. Doing this you will break the cyclic dependency and the design will be more sound.

Note that this is not an issue of the implementation, but of the design. If you really feel that this is the best design for your problem, then you can combine forward declarations with includes as Luchian already mentions.

Comment: +1 For suggesting fix to the real problem rather than workarounds. The forward declaration workarounds will sooner or later cause pain.